# Internet Explorer automation not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, autoit

```
#include <IE.au3>
Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://google.com")
_IELoadWait($oIE)
While 1
_IENavigate($oIE, "http://mywebsite")
_IELoadWait($oIE)
_IELinkClickByText($oIE, "1oZMQ2E")
sleep(600)
WEnd
```

This script is doing endless looping in Windows XP and 7 without any  problem.

But in Windows 8.1 and 8 its not working. Only opening page and remains there. No looping. I tried other scripts but same thing happening. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Using _IECreateEmbedded will make IE work in compatibility mode (IE8).

If thats now what you need, you can run this code once and then all IE instances will run in compatibility mode.

```
#RequireAdmin
    $64Bit = ""
    If @OSArch = "X64" Then
        $64Bit = "64"
    EndIf
If StringLeft(RegRead("HKLM" & $64Bit & "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector", "IE"), 1) > 8 Then ;Check for version 9 or later


  $wshNetwork = ObjCreate("WScript.Network")
  $struser = $wshNetwork.Username
  $objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
  $objAccount = $objWMIService.Get('Win32_UserAccount.Name="' & $struser & '",Domain="' & @ComputerName & '"')
  RegWrite("HKU" & $64Bit & "\" & $objAccount.SID & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
  RegWrite("HKU\" & $objAccount.SID & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
EndIf
```